# How to create this hashmap?

Tags: clojure, hashmap

Basically what I'm trying to do is print a hashmap that contains keys that are characters in a string, and these keys have value 1. For example, string "aabbce" should give a dictionary {:a 1 :b 1 :c 1}.
The following is my attempt but it just prints the empty hashmap

```
(defn isValid [s]
    (def dict {})

    (map (fn [x] ((assoc dict :x 1))) (seq s))

    (println dict)

)
```

Comment: Is a hashmap the best solution for your problem? it looks like you just want to check if a certain character is contained in the string, removing duplicates, which is something that a Set may represent better (no need for the 1 value for each key). Also, a common mistake when learning Clojure is to use `def` inside a form. What it actually does is to define a "top level variable". What you want instead is a let form, as in `(let [dict {}] ...`

Comment: What happened to the final `\e` in `"aabbce"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> (into {} (for [c "aabbce"] [(keyword (str c)) 1]))
{:a 1, :b 1, :c 1, :e 1}
```

`into {} ... sequence of pairs ...` is often a convenient way to create hashmaps. For example

```
> (into {} [[:x 1] [:y "foo"]])
{:x 1, :y "foo"}
```

and `for [item collection] [(key-from item) (value-from item)]` can be a nice way to iterate over a collection to create that list of key-value pairs.

```
> (for [color ["red" "blue" "green"]] [(clojure.string/upper-case color) (count color)])
(["RED" 3] ["BLUE" 4] ["GREEN" 5])
```

I find that putting those together is often the trick for when I want to create a hashmap:

```
> (into {} (for [color ["red" "blue" "green"]] [(clojure.string/upper-case color) (count color)]))
{"RED" 3, "BLUE" 4, "GREEN" 5}
```

Comment: and suppose if instead of just having the value 1, I would like the frequency of the characters? I tried (def dict (into {} (for [c s] [(keyword (str c)) (+(dict (keyword (str c))) 1)]))) but it didn't work because the key doesn't exist initially I suppose.

Comment: Okay, I tried this for counting frequency:
    (def dict (into {} (for [c s] [(keyword (str c)) 
        (if (contains? dict (keyword (str c)))
        (+(dict (keyword (str c))) 1)
        (0))
        ])))

but get the an error

Comment: `> (into {} (for [[k v] (frequencies "aabbce")] [(keyword (str k)) v]))`

Comment: In this case there's a built-in `frequencies` function that gets you most of the way there.

Answer (score 5):

another way is:

```
(zipmap (map (comp keyword str) "abc") (repeat 1))

;;=> { :a 1 :b 1 :c 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You've broken several guidelines of Clojure programming:

- Don't print a result - return it.
- Don't use `def` for locals. Use `let`.
- Don't force the use of keywords. Map keys don't need to be keywords.
- Don't try to assign to names. Use the amended result of a function.

To do the last thing here, use `reduce` instead of `map`. And the `seq` is redundant: functions such as `map` and `reduce` will treat a string as a sequence of characters. So ...

```
(defn isValid [s]
  (reduce (fn [dict x] (assoc dict x 1)) {} s))
```

For example ...

```
=> (isValid "aabbce" )
{\a 1, \b 1, \c 1, \e 1}
```

The local `dict` and the initial value `{}` have been captured by the `reduce`.

---

Why map to `1`? Is this just a set in disguise? If so, ...

```
(defn isValid [s]
  (set s))
```

Or just ...

```
(def isValid set)
```

For example,

```
=> (isValid "aabbce" )
#{\a \b \c \e}
```

You'll find this with functional programming. Boilerplate code melts away like snow in a Chinook wind.

---

A final trivial gripe. `isValid` is camel case. The Clojure conventions are

- kebab case and
- trailing `?` for predicates.

So `valid?` instead of `isValid`.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to implement this leveraging on the large number of functions in the Clojure core library. This is one of the common issues that happens to every new dev coming to Clojure: You think you need to write a function yourself, but actually something already exists, it's just that you don't know it's name yet, so the [Clojure cheat-sheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet) might come handy.

Let's start with the string `aabbce`. You want to remove the duplicates, so `(set "aabbce")` would read the string as a **collection of chars** and create a set out of them. You can use the `map` function to take each character and turn it into a keyword. The problem is that the `keyword` function takes a string, not a char, so we need to use `str` on each char first.

Once we have a sequence of keywords, one simple way of constructing the map is using the `frequencies` function, it will create a hash-map of each element in the collection of keywords with the keyword as the key, and the number of times it appears in the collection as the value, and since we already removed the duplicates, we're guaranteed that each value will be just `1`.

Putting everything together:

```clj
(defn is-valid? [s]
  (frequencies
   (map (comp keyword str)  ;; Turns \a into :a for every letter in the set
        (set s))))          ;; remove duplicates, yields: (\a, \b, \c, \e)

;; or, using the ->> macro:

(defn is-valid? [s]
  (->> (set s)                   ;; turn string into set of chars
       (map (comp keyword str))  ;; turn chars into keywords
       frequencies))             ;; compute occurrences hash-map

;; (println (is-valid? "aabbce"))
;; => {:a 1, :b 1, :c 1, :e 1}
```

Now, the name *isValid* suggests that you want to use this function as a predicate (eg. return `true` or `false` depending on the input). Maybe want to build a function that checks that a string is composed of certain letters?